# Delphi Community Edition Not working Post installation

Tags: delphi

I have downloaded Delphi Community Edition 10.3 from Embarcadero site. After keying in the community edition license the installation progress and fails in the end with below error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall Delphi?

Comment: The error message let me think that for some reason you erased the IDE program (bds.exe is the IDE executable). Probably, you'll have to reinstall from the start.

Comment: Did you verify the EXE is actually present in the path shown? If it does, then the error could mean a *dependent* file is not found. A tool like SysInternals Process Monitor can tell you exactly which file is missing.

Comment: Embarcdero offers free support for installation issues, even for the Community Edition. You should open a ticket on their site.

Comment: yes i tried reinstalling delphi, deleting delphi multiple times it always fails with this error. I dont see the file in the path but in start menu delphi app is created (windows 10)

Comment: Have you installed Delphi in default location or have you perhaps chosen a different folder. Also check your AntiVirus software to make sure it isn't blocking Delphi executable.

Comment: Installed in default location zero customisation on installation procedure

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Dotnet framework first. It seems the installer does not take care of that.